# For compact $K \subset \mathbb C$, show that $u(z) = -\log(\mathrm{dist}(z,K))$ is subharmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $K \subset \mathbb C$ be compact, and let $u(z) = -\log(\mathrm{dist}(z,K))$ be defined on $\mathbb C \setminus K$.  May I get a hint for proving that $u(z)$ is subharmonic?

Subharmonic, here, is defined as u.s.c. and also satisfies the sub-mean-value property.  For $C^2$ functions, $f$ is subharmonic $\iff \Delta f \geq 0$.

**Current work:**

Set $U = \mathbb C \setminus K$.  For a $w \in \mathbb \partial U$, we set $u_w(z) = -\log|z-w|$.  Then $u_w$ can be shown to be harmonic (it's rather straightforward to compute the Laplacian).  Moreover, it is clear that $\displaystyle u(z) = \inf_{w \in \partial U}u_w(z)$.  But I'm having trouble showing that $u$ is therefore subharmonic.  I have the feeling I'm just missing something trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is continuous, OK.

Oh, it seems that the function $\rho  \mapsto - \log \rho $ is decreasing so your function is a supremum in fact 
$z \mapsto  u(z) =\sup_{w} (-\log (|z-w|))= \sup_w\, u_w(z) $, the poinwise supremum of a family of harmonic functions. The harmonic functions $u_w(\cdot)$ have the  [mean value property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property). It follows that the supremum of the family satisfies the [mean value inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subharmonic_function#Subharmonic_functions_in_the_complex_plane), and therefore the function $u$ is subharmonic.